# Error when creating new app with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I installed rails on windows with RailsInstaller and when i try to create a new application with command e.g.

```
rails new blog
```

it creates a lot of files but after it `Using turbolinks 2.2.2` it returns an error to me:

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/tzinfo-data-1.2014.3.gem. It may be corrupted.
```

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a corrupted gem file (maybe due to network download issue).

Go to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\cache\` and delete the file called `tzinfo-data-1.2014.3.gem`.

Then run the `rails new blog` command again and it should work.

Comment: same error, i try also
"gem install tzinfo-data"
but returns another error to me

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    unknown encoding name - CP720